# What is the replacement of daemonize() kernal api in 3.x kernel

Tags: linux-kernel, kernel, porting

I am working on a project that is migrating from linux kernel 2.6 to 3.10.

The 2.6 version contained calls to api **daemonize()** which is not longer available in newer kernel.

So far i have seen [**kthread_run**()](http://review.whamcloud.com/#/c/5655/) as a replacement. However, when i put in kernel_thread() with function to start, null and string name as arguments, i got lots of : **"can't fork"** errors.

Can any one advice upon the correct replacement?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To manage a kernel thread, you should use the helper functions in `<linux/kthread.h>` such as `kthread_run()`.

Comment: Thank you, i noticed that in the link i pasted above. However, i probably just tried replacing calls to daemonize with kthread_run() which results in failures at run time like "can't fork". Do you mean to REMOVE daemonize and instead of kernel_thread(), using kthread_run() to start the thread? Thanks?

Comment: You have to use API correctly. How exactly depends on what your code does.

Comment: Irrespective of what code does, the difference that i felt and wanted to confirm was "kthread_run is not a one to one replacement of daemonize. Daemonize wakes up an already created thread with kernelthread or something. But when you create a thread with kthread_run, daemonize is no longer needed".  IS THAT UNDERSTANDING CORRECT?

Comment: Thank you - appreciate that.